# Facebook SDK share on iOS returns share was cancelled

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-sharer

I'm sharing to Facebook with FB share dialog like this:

```
                        guard let localIdentifier = localIdentifier else {return}
                    let assetURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=" + localIdentifier + "&ext=MOV"

                    let video : FBSDKShareVideo = FBSDKShareVideo()
                    video.videoURL = URL(string:assetURL)
                    let content : FBSDKShareVideoContent = FBSDKShareVideoContent()
                    content.video = video

                    let shareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
                    shareDialog.shareContent = content
                    shareDialog.delegate = self

                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0  , execute: {
                        shareDialog.show()
                    })
```

I check that the url is valid. This is a local MOV file and I copy it first to the camera roll. Then I retrieve it using PHManager and trying to share with FBSDK share dialog.

The FB sharing dialog with the movie appears and I press post. The FB seems processes the file and I get a V - that probably the video was shared.Afterwards I get the callback the share was cancelled. Did somebody experience the same? What might be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately with the iOS 11 update the social network services (Facebook, Twitter, Vimeo, and Flickr), which used to have single sign-on for systemwide integration have been removed.

Comment: So how can we share to Facebook now?

Comment: need to use FBSDK for that  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Comment: But that's what i do exactly! Using FBSDKShareKit, not social framework

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: The only way I can do it so far, is without the dialog and use FBSDKShareAPI.share(with: content, delegate:self). Only problem is that it does not show the dialog or open Facebook! Maybe just put something there that indicates that it will be shared.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the FacebookSDK are you using? I had this problem too and it was because the version that I was using was not compatible with iOS 11 yet. I think that from v 4.27 it's compatible, I was using v4.23. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using 4.27.1 and the device is running 10.3.3 it's iPhone 5. The thing is that after the sharing is finished I'm getting the V sign with label Shared as a confirmation. In reality when running from debugger I get share was cancelled. I print in the sharerDidCancel delegate